# why my width and height are changing when I change my view on my tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My app is made for only landscape view, and what I need is that when it's on portrait it will rotate and show me the landscape view so that i can force the user to see the app in landscape. Though I have a problem, and I am very confused right now. Maybe I am not seeing the problem.

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

var all = document.getElementById("slider-view");

var winWidth            = 0;
var winHeight           = 0;        

// If there are matches, we're in portrait
if(mql.matches) {  
    // Portrait orientation
    $(all).addClass('portrait-transform');

    $(all).css('height', window.innerWidth);
    $(all).css('width', window.innerHeight);
    $(all).css('top', (window.innerHeight - window.innerWidth) / 2);
    $(all).css('left', (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight) / 2);

    winWidth            = window.innerHeight;
    winHeight           = window.innerWidth; 

    alert('height '+ $(all).css('height')+' width '+$(all).css('width')+' top '+$(all).css('top')+' left '+$(all).css('left'));                 

} else {  
    // Landscape orientation
    $('#slider-view').removeClass('portrait-transform');  

    all.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    all.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";

    winWidth            = window.innerWidth;
    winHeight           = window.innerHeight;

    alert('height '+ $(all).css('height')+' width '+$(all).css('width')+' top '+$(all).css('top')+' left '+$(all).css('left'));                 

}

// Add a media query change listener
mql.addListener(function(m) {
    if(m.matches) {
        // Changed to portrait
        $(all).addClass('portrait-transform');

        $(all).css('height', window.innerWidth);
        $(all).css('width', window.innerHeight);
        $(all).css('top', (window.innerHeight - window.innerWidth) / 2);
        $(all).css('left', (window.innerwidth - window.innerheight) / 2);

        alert('height '+ $(all).css('height')+' width '+$(all).css('width')+' top '+$(all).css('top')+' left '+$(all).css('left'));                 


    }
    else {
        // Changed to landscape
        $(all).removeClass('portrait-transform');

        $(all).css('height', window.innerWidth);
        $(all).css('width', window.innerHeight);
        $(all).css('top', 0);
        $(all).css('left', 0);          

        var winWidth            = window.innerWidth;
        var winHeight           = window.innerHeight;

    }
});
```

And I have this for the css

```
.portrait-transform {
/* portrait-specific styles */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* WebKit */
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Mozilla */
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Internet Explorer */
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform: rotate(90deg); /* CSS3 */    
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

}

I need help to understand why my height and width values change when I change the view.